# codeigniter how to manipulate value between tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

can some1 help me with manipulating value between two tables?

Example:

**table 1:**

```
No.   Name       Unit
1     snack       10
```

**table 2:**

```
No.   name       buy
1     emily       5
```

what im want to do is, if *emily* bought *5* units then **table 1** result should be left *5* units..

`unit = unit - buy` 
----> how to translate this into codeigniter???
if can, give me the link to some tutor about manipulating table value in database...

Comment: On a sidenote, you are not recording if _emily_ bought _snack_ or something else from _table 1_. Or this _table 2_ the _snack_ table?

Comment: While inserting on table 2 you need to execute one more query to deduct unit from table1. Trigger would be good solution.

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger, i forgot to put query from table 1 to table 2... in table 2, should have name from table 1.... but, i still cant figure out how to do implement the manipulating data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Update `Table1` when some one brought somthing:

Like:

```
$this->db->update('table1', array('Unit' => 'Unit - ' . (int) $buy, FALSE));
```

if you want any condition try this:

```
$this->db->where('id', 1);//static id 1
$this->db->update('table1', array('Unit' => 'Unit - ' . (int) $buy, FALSE));
```

**Note:** **id** is column name of `Table1`

**Note:** You need to check **Out of Stock Condition** also.

Answer (score 0):

EllisLab has a pretty self-explanatory tutorial for using their included `database` class [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/examples.html). This is how you would load their class:

```
$this->load->database(); //or changing some specifications in config/autoload.php
```

This is how you would query and pull the data from the table:

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT unit FROM table1');
$query2 = $this->db->query('SELECT buy FROM table2');

$row= $query->row();
$buy=$row->unit;

$row2= $query->row();
$unit=$row2->buy;
```

For the actual insertion itself, assuming you've already queried the values of `$buy` and `$unit`:

```
$unit = $unit - $buy;
$sql = "UPDATE table1 SET buy=$unit 
    WHERE buy=($unit - $buy)";

$this->db->query($sql);
```